# Which weapons have splash damage in Torchlight 2?

Tags: torchlight-2

As an Engineer I like using two-handed weapons because of the [Heavy Lifting](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Heavy_Lifting) passive skill that gives bonus attack speed and stun chance. However, I'm not sure if the Greathammer I'm currently using causes [splash damage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96037/1721), so I'm wondering if I should try another two-handed.

Which weapon types in Torchlight 2 cause splash damage (in particular, two-handed weapons), and how large is the splash arc and splash damage dealt by each weapon type?

Comment: In terms of basic attacks, all melee weapons, with the exception of claw-class, splash to multiple targets. This includes staves.

Projectile Weapons (all ranged weapons including wands) never splash.

Comment: @RavenDreamer So I can keep using my Greathammer :) but do you know if the damage and arc varies for weapons that splash?

Comment: @SadlyNot It does. I can't remember where I read the differences between the weapon types, but if I do I'll answer.

Comment: Don't shotguns splash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked up all the weapon types in Torchlight 2.  Here is the complete table.

```
| Weapon      | Hands | Range | Arc        | Splash Damage |

|:------------|:-----:|:------|:-----------|:-------------:|

| Polearm     | 2     | 3m    |120 degrees | 50%           |

| Greatmace   | 2     | 2m    |120 degrees | 50%           |

| Greatsword  | 2     | 2m    |120 degrees | 50%           |

| Greataxe    | 2     | 2m    |120 degrees | 50%           |

| Greathammer | 2     | 2m    |120 degrees | 50%           |

| Staff       | 2     | 2m    |100 degrees | 50%           |

| Mace        | 1     | 1.8m  |60 degrees  | 25%           |

| Sword       | 1     | 1.8m  |60 degrees  | 25%           |

| Axe         | 1     | 1.8m  |60 degrees  | 25%           |

| Claw        | 1     | 1.7m  |0 degrees   | 0%            |

| Bow         | 2     | 10.2m |0 degrees   | 0%            |

| Crossbow    | 2     | 13.2m |0 degrees   | 0%            |

| Cannon      | 2     | 6m    |55 degrees  | 50%           |

| Shotgun     | 2     | 5m    |30 degrees  | 30%           |

| Pistol      | 1     | 7.2m  |0 degrees   | 0%            |

| Wand        | 1     | 7.2m  |0 degrees   | 0%            |
```

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the splash arc radius, distance, and % of full damage that splash attacks do for your current weapon by looking at the Arcane Statistics panel.